# Issues trying to write an SQL query on snowflake that checks if datatype is timestamp

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to write an sql on snowflake that checks if a column data type `(value)` is timestamp

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 2022-01-14 15:03:43:000 |

```
select value from cat
where is_date(value)
```

if value is timestamp, to return 1 and 0 if its not a timestamp

Comment: What happens if the data type is timestamp? Maybe give an example of expected input and output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [TRY_TO_DATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html)/[TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_timestamp.html) functions:

```
SELECT value
FROM tab
WHERE TRY_TO_DATE(value) IS NOT NULL;
```

If a specific date format is expected it could be provided i.e.: `TRY_TO_DATE(value, 'dd-MM-yyyy')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below format and try_to_timestamp returns NULL in case if it is invalida data and also you can  apply format of Timestamp.

```
select try_to_timestamp('2022-01-14 15:03:43','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), try_to_date('Invalid');
```